# Why cant devices not under my router IP connect to my websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I've been at this for days now and this is probably my final attempt at this. Here is the server code to create the websocket.:

```html
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const randomstring = require('randomstring')

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  server: https.createServer({
      key: fs.readFileSync("./private.key"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("./certificate.crt"),
      ca: fs.readFileSync("./ca_bundle.crt")
  }
  ).listen(8080)
});
```

After running this the websocket is hosted on localhost. I connected my godaddy domain to my router private DNS so websocket requests should be sent to my IP. But if i try to connect, say using my phone on LTE using a websocket app, i can't. I can connect fine when the devices are on my IP address.
I try to connect to the socket through godaddy domain like this:

```html
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://mppchatclient.info:8080/');

ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    ws.send('Hi this is web client.');
};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
};
```

[GoDaddy DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eU1V.png)

Comment: Did you configure your router for **port forwarding** from the WAN IP/port to the server LAN IP/port? That is required in this scenario. Also, you would need to use your router’s WAN IP in the DNS record, not a private LAN IP as you have shown. Also, does your router’s internet connection use a static or dynamic IP from your ISP? If dynamic, then GoDaddy DNS won’t work, you would need to use a service like DynDNS instead. Check your router settings, many routers have built-in support for notifying such services when the WAN IP changes.

Comment: Yep, i eventually figured that out! Thanks for the comment anyway.